# Demand Function and Dead Weight Loss

Tags: derivatives, optimization, economics

A. The demand function is given by p=20-q where p is price and q is quantity. Your cost function is c(q)=q^2.

1. How many units should you produce and what price should charge to maximize profits?  What would profits be?
2. Calculate the dead weight loss

For #1 I calculated 20- q = 2q.  Q = 6.67  p = 13.33  Profit = 44.42.  Does anyone know if this correct?  I find it weird that q could be a decimal.

#2, I am not sure how to caluclate dead weight loss...do  you need a p2 and q2?  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: No it is not right. The revenue is $R(q)=p(q)\cdot q=20q-q^2$. Thus the profit is $P(q)=p(q)     \cdot q-C(q)=20q-q^2-q^2=20q-2q^2$.

 Calculate the derivative w.r.t $q$ and set it equal to $0$: $P^{'}(q)=0$. Finally solve for $q$.

Comment: so is it 20 - 2q = 0.  q = 10??

Comment: No, the derivative of $ 2q^2$ is $4q$. Therefore $20-4q=0\Rightarrow q^*=5\Rightarrow p^*=15$

Answer (score 0):

The demand is $q=20-p$.

Your revenue is $r=qp=20p-p^2$

Your net profit is $n=r-c=r-q^2=60p-2p^2-400$

which is maximised when $\frac{\partial n}{\partial p}=0$

Accordingly, the solution of $p_*=60-4p_*$ gives the optimum price  of $p=15$

I found this definition of "Deadweight Loss" from Wikipedia:
"In economics, a deadweight loss (also known as excess burden or allocative inefficiency) is a loss of economic efficiency that can occur when equilibrium for a good or service is not achieved or is not achievable. "

This requires knowledge of a supply function though, which I did not notice in the problem specs. I may be missing something.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 20 - 2q = 0.  q = 10?  Then p = 10?

Comment: No, the derivative of the profit function is $20-4q$. The second term in the PF is $-2q^2$

Comment: So p = 15 making q = 5...correct?

Comment: Yes. Still stumped on the "deadweight loss" part of the problem, though.

Comment: It's tough...i think you are correct and need to find the area of a triangle on the supply curve.  However, I am also seeing you need variables of p2 and q2...so not sure either.  Thank  you for your help

Comment: Do you know how the problem changes if you behave like a competitive firm?  How do you solve for p,q?  Does it change at all?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
p(q)&=20-q\\
c (q)&=q^2\\
r (q)&=p (q) \times q=20q-q^2\\
\pi (q)&=r (q)- c(q)=20q-2q^2\\
\\
\pi'(q)&=20-4q=0\quad \Longrightarrow \quad q_m=5,\; p_m=20-q_m=15,\;\pi (q_m)=\pi_m=20q_m-2q_m^2=50
\end{align}
$$

The marginal cost is $c'(q)=2q $. The equilibrium is $c'(q)=p (q) $ that is $q_e=\frac{20}{3},\,p_e=\frac{40}{3}$. So the dead weight loss is 
$$
D=\frac{1}{2}(p_m-p_e)(q_e-q_m)=1.39
$$